# Словообразование слово "плёнка"

Tags: словообразование

Добрый день. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобрать слово по составу **плёнка**. В словарях указывается корень *плёнк-*. Этимология слова - пелена. Почему К входит в корень?

Comment: Потому что синхронисты-вредители стараются скрыть связи между словами.

Comment: Слова "стол" "престол" столица" исторически родственные слова. Здесь вы тоже будете настаивать, что корень в этих словах - стол? И что "синхронисты-вредители стараются скрыть связи между словами."

Comment: Разумеется, корень тут один. Попытки скрыть это, прикрываясь "современным уровнем", "синхронизмом",  я считаю заблуждением, либо вредительством.

Comment: Если вы на современном уровне выделяете здесь корень стол, что же...  Вы будучи нелингвистом, выдвигаете ни ем необоснованные мнения... Покажите мне хоть один морфемно -словообразовательный словарь ( современный) где между этими словами будет прямые словообразовательные связи.

Comment: И я выделяю, и все диахронисты. То, что современные словари зиждутся на синхронистском подходе, я не отрицал.

Comment: Ну вот я и о том же. Вы делаете ни чем не обоснованные заявления. А доказать свою точку зрения научно сможете?

Comment: Я, не будучи лингвистом, выдвигаю обоснованное требование: перестать мутить воду. Любому русскоязычному человеку очевидно, что между словами **столица** и **престол** есть прямая смысловая связь, как же не выделить тут корень **стол**?

Answer (score 5):

Пелен/а, пелен/а/ть, пелён/к/а, плёнк/а - в этих словах выделяется исторический корень **pellas** (греч.) - кожица, пленка.

В современном языке все они имеют различное значение: **пелёнка** - детская простынка, **пелена** - сплошной покров, заволакивающий что-то со всех сторон, **плёнка** - многозначное слово с общим значение тонкой ткани, оболочки.

Соответственно, между словами "пелена, пеленать, плёнка" нет прямых словообразовательных связей.

Answer (score 2):

Хотя **пленка** исторически восходит к слову **пелена**, сегодня эти слова уже разошлись в значениях и стали самостоятельными словами. Иначе говоря, если мы будет выделять корень **пелен** и суффикс к, получится, что пленка - это уменьшительно-ласкательное от **пелена.**

Comment: А это не так, что ли?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Вы полагаете, что нельзя представить *плёнку* как маленькую *пелену*?

Comment: Нет. Пленка и пелена не то же самое.

Comment: Откройте толковые словари и посмотрите. Пелена — покров, плёнка — тонкий покров. Суть в этом.

Comment: Вы не читаете ответы и не понимаете суть: на современном уровне эти слова не связаны. У Кузнецова указано: пелена. ***устар.*** Пелёнки

Comment: Суть, как я увидел ещё во время нашей беседы по поводу диахронизма и синхронизма, не понимаете Вы.